# Select an element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey Stackoverflow developers, I have this code

```
    <div id="1"></div><div id="2"></div><div id="3"></div><div id="4"></div><div id="5"></div><br>  
        <div id="6"></div><div id="7"></div><div id="8"></div><div id="9"></div><div id="10"></div><br>
        <div id="11"></div><div id="12"></div><div id="13"></div><div id="14"></div><div id="15"></div><br>
        <div id="16"></div><div id="17"></div><div id="18"></div><div id="19"></div><div id="20"></div><br>
        <div id="21"></div><div id="22"></div><div id="23"></div><div id="24"></div><div id="25"></div><br>        

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../sketch.js"></script>
        <script>
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].addEventListener("click", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
</script>
```

I want to be able to click on a div and for *Javascript* (not jQuery) to change the background color of *only* the clicked div. I've tried everything. How do I do it?

Comment: Rather than adding a listener to every div, consider adding a listener to a parent and using `event.target` to discover the element that was clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()` to select all `div` elements with an `id`, iterate `NodeList` of `div` elements, attach `click` handler within a loop

```html
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div><br>
<div id="6"></div>
<div id="7"></div>
<div id="8"></div>
<div id="9"></div>
<div id="10"></div><br>
<div id="11"></div>
<div id="12"></div>
<div id="13"></div>
<div id="14"></div>
<div id="15"></div><br>
<div id="16"></div>
<div id="17"></div>
<div id="18"></div>
<div id="19"></div>
<div id="20"></div><br>
<div id="21"></div>
<div id="22"></div>
<div id="23"></div>
<div id="24"></div>
<div id="25"></div><br>

<script>
  let divs = document.querySelectorAll("div[id]");
  for (let div of divs) {
    div.textContent = div.id;
    div.addEventListener("click", displayDate);
  }

  function displayDate() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: All the answers were amazing! Thank you community! But this one can refer to a div without mentioning it explicitly and that is what I was trying to solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your div wasn't visible because it had no content and there for no height or width. I added height and width with css and then it worked.
 You could also add content as suggested above.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName( 'test' )[0].addEventListener( 'click', function( event ){
 this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
});
```

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

div is ignored when there is no value/text. Your code is fine. Just add something to the div.

```html
    <div id="1">some value</div><div id="2"></div><div id="3"></div><div id="4"></div><div id="5"></div><br>  
        <div id="6"></div><div id="7"></div><div id="8"></div><div id="9"></div><div id="10"></div><br>
        <div id="11"></div><div id="12"></div><div id="13"></div><div id="14"></div><div id="15"></div><br>
        <div id="16"></div><div id="17"></div><div id="18"></div><div id="19"></div><div id="20"></div><br>
        <div id="21"></div><div id="22"></div><div id="23"></div><div id="24"></div><div id="25"></div><br>        

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.11/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../sketch.js"></script>
        <script>
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].addEventListener("click", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
</script>
```